# Short story involving two AI negotiating the terms of an insurance claim about an ongoing car accident, all within a few milliseconds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, artificial-intelligence

I remember having read this story on some blog.

Each car has a central computer with an AI running in each one. They got into a head-on collision but one of the cars can survive if they both agree to take certain actions, though the other one would certainly imply the death of the inhabitants.

The two AI review the terms of both of their insurance policies and enter into a negotiation as to which one should be the surviving car. They go about different scenarios and eventually reach an agreement. At the end, we discover that all this conversation happened in just a few milliseconds.

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: Likely a duplicate of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195755/20774). The answer was *Override* by James Yu.

Comment: *Possibly* a dupe of [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/277243/20774). The answer was *Parking Spaces* by Henry Melton. Unlikely to be the right answer, but a very slim chance

Comment: Marlinski: if it is [Override](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195755/20774) (which seems very likely) please let us know and we'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, it really reads like the right answer. You guys are fast !

Comment: Your question has been closed. Since you clarified in a comment that it's the same answer to an accepted question, our dupe-policy for [tag:story-identification] applies. You will still receive points for upvotes, and this does not mean it's a bad question. Obviously, it was a good enough one that people recognized it has one we'd had before.